# Shiny UI and Server Loops

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create something that looks like this:

[image]

Sample code:

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

```
data <- data_frame(
  category = c(rep("Superhero outfits", 5), "Game of Thrones houses", rep("My favourite bars", 2), "I am groot"),
  keywords = c("superman + red + cape", "Batman + black + cape", "Hulk + green + purple", "Spiderman + web", "Groot + wood + plant", "wolf + stark",
               "chocolate + nuts", "protein + cookie", "I + groot"),
  author = c(rep("Preter Parker", 3), rep("Bruce Wayne", 5), "Groot"),
  date = c(rep(Sys.Date()))
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "MyApp"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
       column(
         selectizeInput("selectCategory", NULL, choices = unique(data$category)),
         uiOutput("displayChoicesUI"),
         width = 4
     ) 
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    choices_list <- reactive({
      if(!is.null(input$selectCategory)){
      data %>%
      filter(category == input$selectCategory) %>%
      mutate(ID = row_number())
      }
    })

    output$displayChoicesUI <- renderUI({
      if(!is.null(input$selectCategory)){

        lapply(1:nrow(choices_list), function(i){
          column(
            width = 12,
            column(
              width = 8,
              verbatimTextOutput(paste0("text_", choices_list$ID[i]))
            ),
            column(
              width = 2,
              actionLink(paste0("delete_", choices_list$ID[i]), HTML("<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>"))
            ),
            column(
              width = 2,
              actionLink(paste0("edit_", choices_list$ID[i]), HTML("<i class='fa fa-edit'></i>"))
            )
          )
        })
      }
    })

    lapply(1:????, function(i){
                      output[[paste0("text_", i)]] <- renderText({
                        HTML(paste0(choices_list()$keywods[i], br(), choices_list()$author, ", ", choices_list()$date))
                      })
                    })

    lapply(1:????, function(i){
          observeEvent(input[[paste0("delete_", i)]], {
          })
    })

    lapply(1:????, function(i){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("edit_", i)]], {
      })
    })


  }
)
```

The question is, since I do not know how many keywords there will be in the category, how do I loop through it to create reactivity - output the keywords and authors and make buttons act.

The number of iteration is a reactive value, however I cannot add a reactive value into lapply. Doing sth like `lapply(1:nrow(choices_list()), function(i){})` gives me `Evaluation error: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.).`

Is there any way I can do what intended or is there a better way to do it? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Add reactive values to your server, then you can loop through them and change them upon reacitve event. You can bind apply to action button. For example add:

To UI:

```
actionButton("press","Press me",icon=icon("smile", lib = "font-awesome"))
```

To server:

```
categorySuperHero <- reactiveValues(data.frame(words=c("cape","superman")))
observeEvent(input$search,{
  categorySuperHero$words <- rbind(categorySuperHero$words,input$search) 
   ## assuming you search one word, otherwise you can break the string and loop through it
})
observeEvent(input$press,{
   x <- apply(categorySuperHero$words,1,function(x){"ur function"})
})
```

If you dont want that user needs to press the button you can simulate (after some condition) action button press with:

```
click(input$press)
```

I hope that I understood your problem correctly and that this helps.

Comment: Its not quite what I had in mind (or I do not understand right what you meant :)), but it gave me an idea on how to solve part of my issue

Comment: Once you got reactive values saved in some variable you can easily update widgets and use that reacitve variable as input (I m thinking of that select widget for categories). You can add "updateSelectInput" (google it) and for choices you can pass that reacitve variable.